# Wave impedance in a wave guide

Tags: electromagnetism, experimental-physics, electrical-resistance, field-theory, waveguide

I'm trying to get a better understanding of impedance for a wave guide. First of all, my current understanding of the topic is that its a ratio of the electric field amplitude over the magnetic field amplitude. I'm also under the impression that a reduction in impedance is good. Why is that? I found this formula for impedance in a wave guide https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_impedance
[image]

In this formula is $f$ the frequency of the light in the wave guide as opposed to the free space frequency? Finally, I have done an experiment on a wave guide. Where I aim to reduce impedance. How can I tell if I was successful? For example, I measured the voltage vs time of the wave guide without a horn on the end, then placed a horn on the end and made the same measurement. The voltage vs time graphs do have different amplitudes, but how can I go from than and calculate impedance in each case?

Edit: I found this site https://www.electronics-notes.com/articles/antennas-propagation/rf-feeders-transmission-lines/waveguide-impedance-characteristic-matching-iris.php . I think it answers my question on what to do with the voltage measurements. But i'm still just not sure what this means. How does this [image]

give impedance?

Comment: I think you should clarify your question, describe the experiment and its results or write some equations where you have a problem, etc.. Eg., "I'm also under the impression that a reduction in impedance is good.", why is this your impression?